# how to set max iterations in cg matrix approximation in c++ eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I'm using a conjugate Gradient (cg) method to approximate an inversion of a matrix using eigen3 package in c++ (cg is one of the iterative solvers of eigen). I want to change the maximum number of iterations but can't figure out how.

In the eigen page it says that it can be controlled via the setMaxIterations() method but I don't know where I need to put this and how to use it. part of the code I'm using is as following;

```
ConjugateGradient<SparseMatrix<double> > cg;
cg.compute(CJ); // CJ is a matrix which is already defined
if (cg.info() != Success) {
                 cout << "Matrix is not invertible." << endl;
                  exit(1);
        }
SparseMatrix<double> IDin(totalJ,totalJ);
IDin.setIdentity();

VectorXd inversevector(totalJ), Idvector(totalJ);


    Idvector = IDin.block(0,0,totalJ,1);

    inversevector = cg.solve(Idvector);
```

I checked and the code reaches the last line but gets stuck in it, so I thought I can decrease the number of iterations as it is by default the size of the problem which in my case is a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConjugateGradient should have this function: `cg.setMaxIterations(int)`.
See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ConjugateGradient.html

Comment: yes, thanks. I just found it after asking the question! the problem was that I didn't know how to use this `setMaxIterations()` now it works perfectly. thanks :)